# Why am I banned from posting?

Tags: support, answers

I answered the questions and suggestions, but I am apparently not allowed to post now. Please explain. I apologise if I overstepped somewhere. I'm new to this exchange.

Comment: Even though this question belongs on [meta] the following 2 pages from the [help] should be helpful: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) and [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: Vakkoo, please know that the close votes that are showing up are actually voting to migrate your question to RPG Meta, since it's not about roleplaying games but rather how the RPG Stack Exchange site works, so the meta site is the appropriate place for it.

Comment: Your answer section is only showing two answers with a total score of -3. Have many of your answers been deleted?

Comment: FWIW, the [tour], [help], [ask] and [answer] provide decent guidance on how to best interact with the site.  I hope you can contribute again when the restriction is removed.  SE sites are not an internet forum; treating a Question and answer collection like a threaded forum discussion doesn't fit this format.  Looking at your two answers, they were ideas and suggestions that weren't supported by the game's rules of play, or by play experience relevant to the question. That is why I suspect they earned down votes.

Answer (score 11):

### You probably triggered an automatic block

See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Relevantly:

> An automatic filter is in place to ban questions or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.
>
> To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.
>
> To help prevent you from encountering a ban, the system will give you a warning if you are on the road to a ban, and may temporarily prevent you from posting questions or answers for a few days. If, despite these warnings and rate limits, you continue to post too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be altogether banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The RPG stack can be a tough crowd. Ideally, there should be a clearly correct answer, based on source materials. 'If it happened at my table, I'd rule it like this' style answers often get downvoted not because they are bad in themselves but because everyone has an opinion and generally we are looking for something more.

As Dale has explained, if your posts are poorly received, this will lead to suspensions, although the details of the algorithm are not public.

Comment: This seems to be addressing an ancillary issue, at best. OP's asking why they can't post, not why they are receiving downvotes.

Comment: @TylerH lots of down votes can lead to the triggers that the auto function Dale addresses uses to make a change to an account

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Hence why it's ancillary (versus 'totally unrelated').